# How can I clean my react-native project to back it up?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, npm

I'm developing a mobile app using React-Native, and as I'm the only developer of it, I don't want to use a versioning tool like git, I don't want to host it on the cloud (trust reasons...), and was wondering how can I make backup of my react-native project, in case of an hardware loss.

The obvious way would be to just archive everything, but it weight 2.2GB and about 800mb once compressed. It's ok for one backup, but what if I want to make regular backups?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## To clean

Clean deriveddata with xcode project

```
cd ios
xcodebuild clean
```

Clean ios build folder

```
rm -rf ios/build
```

Clean ios pods

```
rm -rf ios/Pods
```

Clean android studio

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
```

Clean android build folders

```
rm -rf android/build
rm -rf android/app/build
```

Clean gradle cache

```
rm -rf android/.gradle
```

Clean node modules

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

Clean watchman cache

```
watchman watch-del-all
```

Clean npm cache

```
npm cache clean
```

You can now archive everything!

## To use a backup

Install back package.json's npm modules

```
npm install
```

Install back iOS Pods

```
cd ios/
pod install
```