# About 100 error in Xcode, Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 :upgraded react-native from 0.59.1 to 0.60.5

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I've been trying to upgrade my project and use cocoapods for ios,
Whenever i build from xcode it gives me 100 error related to swift, 
- My project does not depends on swift
- Upgraded all packages

Please find screenshot for error

[PackageList Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/113RAKa5aLGWk1H9q3MXVRDioqmOQ4IYe/view?usp=sharing)!

[Xcode Error Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OgUFNTnxnIgcMDt2DGk1db9hWG9XYvB1/view?usp=sharing)!

[Xcode Error Screenshot1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fzz4hcHj9Sv6KkQb7u_8ee9W8OyM17Ad/view?usp=sharing)!

[Xcode Error Screenshot2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19PhX4agLrJlUbYg7RPnhRueOuCuJPh8T/view?usp=sharing)!

I've followed below link for package upgradation
[react-native-community link](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.59.10&to=0.60.5)!

Same error was found [flutter](https://github.com/kiwi-bop/flutter_crashlytics/issues/29)! - didn't try this

````
# platform :ios, '9.0'

require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'


target 'test' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for test
  # Your 'node_modules' directory is probably in the root of your project,
  # but if not, adjust the `:path` accordingly
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-fishhook', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/fishhook'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTPushNotification', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/PushNotificationIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec =>   '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  pod 'react-native-print', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-print'
  pod 'react-native-webview', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-webview'
  pod 'RNImageCropPicker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker'
  pod 'react-native-sqlite-storage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-sqlite-storage'
  pod 'RNCAsyncStorage', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage'
  pod 'react-native-netinfo', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/netinfo'
  pod 'react-native-contacts', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-contacts'
  pod 'RNFS', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fs'
  pod 'RNGestureHandler', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler'
  pod 'react-native-html-to-pdf', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-html-to-pdf'
  pod 'react-native-image-resizer', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-resizer'
  pod 'RNShare', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-share'
  pod 'react-native-splash-screen', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen'
  pod 'RNSVG', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-svg'
  pod 'ReactNativePermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'
  pod 'lottie-react-native', :path => '../node_modules/lottie-react-native'
  pod 'lottie-ios', :path => '../node_modules/lottie-ios'

  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 6.3.0'

  #pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.9.3', '< 3.0'


  # Required by RNFirebase
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 6.3.0'

  #target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  #  pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.6.2', '< 3.0'
  #end

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'No'
      end
    end
  end

  use_native_modules!
end

target 'test-tvOSTests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for testing
end

target 'testTests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for testing
end

target 'test-tvOS' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

end```


Expecting it should have been worked easily
````

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

1. Open ios/YourAppName.xcodeproj in Xcode
2. Right-click on Your App Name in the Project Navigator on the left, and click New File…
3. Create a single empty Swift file to the project (make sure that Your App Name target is selected when adding)
4. When Xcode asks, press Create Bridging Header and do not remove Swift file then. re-run your build.

This should fix the problem

Found on github: https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/issues/1059#issuecomment-493925940

Comment: This worked for me! But I guess adding Swift file is not the React Native solution. Is there another option?

Answer (score 2):

Please follow these steps:

1. check the app developer id is logged in
2. clean your build for your react native following
   steps: [How can I clean my react-native project to back it up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49603408/how-can-i-clean-my-react-native-project-to-back-it-up)
3. close your Xcode
4. Open your project from xworkspace

Answer (score 2):

This issue can happen because of Xcode 12. I have created a script to fix the issue. You can find it here: https://gist.github.com/HosseinRashno/4786b289356ad9840b6c087ce8191fe4

Here you can find about the reason of the issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29633#issuecomment-694187116

> The issue is that all the podspecs of these libraries that fail to
> link depend on the React pod, which is in fact really only an umbrella
> dependency for pure JS applications to depend on, whereas the native
> APIs that these libraries rely on actually reside in the React-Core
> pod.
>
> This means that they technically were always incorrect—conceptually
> one should always explicitly depend on the lib that provides the APIs
> you rely on, rather than relying on transitive dependencies—but it
> seems like in previous Xcode versions the build system worked
> differently and having the transitive dependencies around just
> happened to work ‍♂️
>
> The correct fix going forward is for all these libs to update their
> dependency from React to React-Core:
>
> Remove:  `s.dependency 'React'`
> Add:  `s.dependency 'React-Core'`

Comment: I've changed from `React` to `React-Core`, it didn't work. I am having react-native-geolocation` issue which has worked on `xcode 11` but doesn't work on `xcode 12`. The problem is `Geolocation.watchposition` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

add this line in YourAppName > Build Setting > Search paths > Framework Search Paths

```
$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift/$(PLATFORM_NAME)
```

and it will work

Answer (score 0):

As final solution wasnt only the embedding of a brigding header, having "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraris" **BUT** having also ANY Swift file in the build target and not only in the pods. Looks like XCode optimizer is removing even if "Always" is YES.