# ios build failed when upgrading xcode version 10.3 to 11.5

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native, cross-platform

My existing react native project has switched from xcode 10.3 to xcode 11.5. I installed it on the new computer, but i can't run on ios. I switched to the recommended settings of Xcode but the problem is not solved.

When i run this code `react-native run-ios --device` i get the following error

**-[NSTaggedPointerString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa29d44a23e70bdc1**

Log

```
info + node /Users/userName/myProject/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev true --reset-cache --bundle-output /Users/userName/myProject/ios/build/myProject/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AppName.app/main.jsbundle --assets-dest /Users/userName/myProject/ios/build/myProject/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AppName.app
info warning: the transform cache was reset.
info Loading dependency graph, done.
info info Writing bundle output to:, /Users/userName/myProject/ios/build/myProject/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AppName.app/main.jsbundle
info info Done writing bundle output
info info Copying 40 asset files
info info Done copying assets
info + cd /Users/userName/myProject/node_modules/react-native-schemes-manager/../..
info + node /Users/userName/myProject/node_modules/react-native-schemes-manager/index.js hide-library-schemes
info Hiding schemes from node_modules xcode projects.
info  - [hide-library-schemes]: node_modules/react-native-calendar-events/RNCalendarEvents.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/will.xcuserdatad/xcschemes skipped
info  - [hide-library-schemes]: node_modules/react-native-calendar-events/RNCalendarEvents.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/wmcmahan.xcuserdatad/xcschemes skipped
info  - [hide-library-schemes]: node_modules/react-native-camera/ios/RNCamera.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/laurin.xcuserdatad/xcschemes skipped
info  - [hide-library-schemes]: node_modules/react-native-cookies/ios/RNCookieManagerIOS.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/jmrodriguez.xcuserdatad/xcschemes skipped
info  - [hide-library-schemes]: node_modules/react-native-cookies/ios/RNCookieManagerIOS.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/josephferraro.xcuserdatad/xcschemes skipped
info  - [hide-library-schemes]: node_modules/react-native-file-opener/ios/RNFileOpener.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/sujiexu.xcuserdatad/xcschemes skipped
info  - [hide-library-schemes]: node_modules/react-native-open-file/ios/RNDocumentInteractionController/RNDocumentInteractionController.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/aarong.xcuserdatad/xcschemes skipped
info  - [hide-library-schemes]: node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/thibault.xcuserdatad/xcschemes skipped
info + [[ true != true ]]
info
info PBXCp build/myProject/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex build/myProject/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AppName.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex
    cd /Users/userName/myProject/ios
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/userName/Library/Android/sdk/emulator:/Users/userName/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/userName/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:/Users/userName/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools"
    builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -exclude Headers -exclude PrivateHeaders -exclude Modules -exclude *.tbd -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/userName/myProject/ios/build/myProject/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex /Users/userName/myProject/ios/build/myProject/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AppName.app/PlugIns
info
info ValidateEmbeddedBinary build/myProject/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AppName.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex
    cd /Users/userName/myProject/ios
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/userName/Library/Android/sdk/emulator:/Users/userName/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/userName/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:/Users/userName/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools"
    builtin-embeddedBinaryValidationUtility /Users/userName/myProject/ios/build/myProject/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AppName.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex -signing-cert 10F03D5D9A5BE1AEAC947715A8BCA40CC9C1F7F7 -info-plist-path /Users/userName/myProject/ios/build/myProject/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AppName.app/Info.plist
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code null. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening myProject.xcworkspace
2020-07-14 09:57:05.870 xcodebuild[1001:17005]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 1caa2627b1bfd5fb37aee41d2c867ca908349a49 was NULL
2020-07-14 10:03:59.298 xcodebuild[1001:21128] -[NSTaggedPointerString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa29d44a23e70bdc1
** INTERNAL ERROR: Uncaught exception **
Uncaught Exception: -[NSTaggedPointerString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa29d44a23e70bdc1
Stack:
  0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2   -[NSObject(NSObject) __retain_OA] (in CoreFoundation)
  3   ___forwarding___ (in CoreFoundation)
  4   _CF_forwarding_prep_0 (in CoreFoundation)
  5   -[XCEmbeddedBinaryValidator isValidWithError:] (in DevToolsCore)
  6   +[XCWorkQueueCommandBuiltinInvocation_embeddedBinaryValidationUtility _runTaskWithInputPath:certSHA1Hash:parentInfoPlistPath:embeddedBinaryCodeSignatureSource:] (in DevToolsCore)
  7   -[XCWorkQueueCommandBuiltinInvocation_embeddedBinaryValidationUtility runTaskWithArguments:environment:workingDirectoryPath:infd:outerrfd:] (in DevToolsCore)
  8   __107-[XCWorkQueueCommandBuiltinInvocation initWithWorkQueueCommand:arguments:environment:workingDirectoryPath:]_block_invoke (in DevToolsCore)
  9   __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ (in Foundation)
 10   -[NSBlockOperation main] (in Foundation)
 11   __NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN__ (in Foundation)
 12   -[NSOperation start] (in Foundation)
 13   __51-[XCWorkQueueCommandBuiltinInvocation startRunning]_block_invoke_3 (in DevToolsCore)
 14   __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ (in DVTFoundation)
 15   __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
 16   _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib)
 17   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 18   _dispatch_continuation_pop (in libdispatch.dylib)
 19   _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 20   _dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 21   _dispatch_worker_thread2 (in libdispatch.dylib)
 22   _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 23   start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
```

On the old machine everything's fine (XCode 10.3, SDK 12.4). But i can't build on new machine (XCode 13.5, SDK 13.5).

Podfile.lock

```
  - boost-for-react-native (1.63.0)
  - BVLinearGradient (2.5.6):
    - React
  - Charts (3.3.0):
    - Charts/Core (= 3.3.0)
  - Charts/Core (3.3.0)
  - DoubleConversion (1.1.6)
  - Firebase/Analytics (6.27.1):
    - Firebase/Core
  - Firebase/Core (6.27.1):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAnalytics (= 6.6.2)
  - Firebase/CoreOnly (6.27.1):
    - FirebaseCore (= 6.8.1)
  - Firebase/MLVision (6.27.1):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseMLVision (~> 0.20.1)
  - Firebase/MLVisionFaceModel (6.27.1):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseMLVisionFaceModel (~> 0.20.0)
  - FirebaseAnalytics (6.6.2):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.8)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 1.4)
    - GoogleAppMeasurement (= 6.6.2)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 6.0)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 6.0)"
    - nanopb (~> 1.30905.0)
  - FirebaseCore (6.8.1):
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (~> 1.3)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.5)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 6.5)
  - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (1.4.0):
    - GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (~> 3.1)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.5)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 6.5)
    - nanopb (~> 1.30905.0)
  - FirebaseInstallations (1.4.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.8)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.6)
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 6.6)
    - PromisesObjC (~> 1.2)
  - FirebaseInstanceID (4.4.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.8)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 1.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.5)
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 6.5)
  - FirebaseMLCommon (0.20.1):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.7)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 4.3)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Logger (~> 2.1)
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)"
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSDictionary+URLArguments (~> 2.1)"
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 6.0)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)
    - Protobuf (~> 3.12)
  - FirebaseMLVision (0.20.1):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.7)
    - FirebaseMLCommon (~> 0.20)
    - GoogleAPIClientForREST/Core (~> 1.3)
    - GoogleAPIClientForREST/Vision (~> 1.3)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Logger (~> 2.1)
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)"
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)
    - Protobuf (~> 3.12)
  - FirebaseMLVisionFaceModel (0.20.0):
    - FirebaseMLVision (~> 0.20)
  - Folly (2018.10.22.00):
    - boost-for-react-native
    - DoubleConversion
    - glog
  - glog (0.3.5)
  - GoogleAPIClientForREST/Core (1.4.2):
    - GTMSessionFetcher (>= 1.1.7)
  - GoogleAPIClientForREST/Vision (1.4.2):
    - GoogleAPIClientForREST/Core
    - GTMSessionFetcher (>= 1.1.7)
  - GoogleAppMeasurement (6.6.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 6.0)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 6.0)"
    - nanopb (~> 1.30905.0)
  - GoogleDataTransport (6.2.1)
  - GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (3.2.0):
    - GoogleDataTransport (~> 6.1)
    - nanopb (~> 1.30905.0)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/DebugUtils (2.2.2):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.2.2)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (2.2.2)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/Logger (2.2.2):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.2.2)
  - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (2.2.2)":
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.2.2)
  - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSDictionary+URLArguments (2.2.2)":
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/DebugUtils (= 2.2.2)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.2.2)
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSString+URLArguments (= 2.2.2)"
  - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSString+URLArguments (2.2.2)"
  - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (6.6.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - GoogleUtilities/Network
  - GoogleUtilities/Environment (6.6.0):
    - PromisesObjC (~> 1.2)
  - GoogleUtilities/Logger (6.6.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
  - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (6.6.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/Network (6.6.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib"
    - GoogleUtilities/Reachability
  - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (6.6.0)"
  - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (6.6.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (6.6.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GTMSessionFetcher (1.4.0):
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Full (= 1.4.0)
  - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (1.4.0)
  - GTMSessionFetcher/Full (1.4.0):
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (= 1.4.0)
  - nanopb (1.30905.0):
    - nanopb/decode (= 1.30905.0)
    - nanopb/encode (= 1.30905.0)
  - nanopb/decode (1.30905.0)
  - nanopb/encode (1.30905.0)
  - OneSignal (2.14.3)
  - Permission-Calendars (2.1.5):
    - RNPermissions
  - Permission-Camera (2.1.5):
    - RNPermissions
  - Permission-Contacts (2.1.5):
    - RNPermissions
  - Permission-FaceID (2.1.5):
    - RNPermissions
  - Permission-LocationAlways (2.1.5):
    - RNPermissions
  - Permission-LocationWhenInUse (2.1.5):
    - RNPermissions
  - Permission-MediaLibrary (2.1.5):
    - RNPermissions
  - Permission-Microphone (2.1.5):
    - RNPermissions
  - Permission-Motion (2.1.5):
    - RNPermissions
  - Permission-Notifications (2.1.5):
    - RNPermissions
  - Permission-PhotoLibrary (2.1.5):
    - RNPermissions
  - Permission-Reminders (2.1.5):
    - RNPermissions
  - Permission-Siri (2.1.5):
    - RNPermissions
  - Permission-SpeechRecognition (2.1.5):
    - RNPermissions
  - Permission-StoreKit (2.1.5):
    - RNPermissions
  - PromisesObjC (1.2.9)
  - Protobuf (3.12.0)
  - React (0.59.10):
    - React/Core (= 0.59.10)
  - react-native-calendar-events (1.7.3):
    - React
  - react-native-camera/FaceDetectorMLKit (2.11.2):
    - Firebase/MLVision
    - Firebase/MLVisionFaceModel
    - React
    - react-native-camera/RCT
    - react-native-camera/RN
  - react-native-camera/RCT (2.11.2):
    - React
  - react-native-camera/RN (2.11.2):
    - React
  - react-native-image-picker (0.28.1):
    - React
  - react-native-netinfo (5.9.4):
    - React
  - react-native-onesignal (3.9.0):
    - OneSignal (= 2.14.3)
    - React (< 1.0.0, >= 0.13.0)
  - react-native-webview (5.12.1):
    - React
  - React/Core (0.59.10):
    - yoga (= 0.59.10.React)
  - React/CxxBridge (0.59.10):
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - React/Core
    - React/cxxreact
    - React/jsiexecutor
  - React/cxxreact (0.59.10):
    - boost-for-react-native (= 1.63.0)
    - DoubleConversion
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
    - React/jsinspector
  - React/DevSupport (0.59.10):
    - React/Core
    - React/RCTWebSocket
  - React/fishhook (0.59.10)
  - React/jsi (0.59.10):
    - DoubleConversion
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
  - React/jsiexecutor (0.59.10):
    - DoubleConversion
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
    - React/cxxreact
    - React/jsi
  - React/jsinspector (0.59.10)
  - React/RCTActionSheet (0.59.10):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTAnimation (0.59.10):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTBlob (0.59.10):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTGeolocation (0.59.10):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTImage (0.59.10):
    - React/Core
    - React/RCTNetwork
  - React/RCTLinkingIOS (0.59.10):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTNetwork (0.59.10):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTSettings (0.59.10):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTText (0.59.10):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTVibration (0.59.10):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTWebSocket (0.59.10):
    - React/Core
    - React/fishhook
    - React/RCTBlob
  - RNCAsyncStorage (1.11.0):
    - React
  - RNPermissions (2.1.5):
    - React
  - RNShare (1.2.1):
    - React
  - RNSVG (7.2.1):
    - React
  - SwiftyJSON (5.0.0)
  - yoga (0.59.10.React)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - BVLinearGradient (from `../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient`)
  - Charts (= 3.3.0)
  - DoubleConversion (from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`)
  - Firebase/Analytics
  - Folly (from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`)
  - glog (from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`)
  - Permission-Calendars (from `../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/Calendars.podspec`)
  - Permission-Camera (from `../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/Camera.podspec`)
  - Permission-Contacts (from `../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/Contacts.podspec`)
  - Permission-FaceID (from `../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/FaceID.podspec`)
  - Permission-LocationAlways (from `../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/LocationAlways.podspec`)
  - Permission-LocationWhenInUse (from `../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/LocationWhenInUse.podspec`)
  - Permission-MediaLibrary (from `../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/MediaLibrary.podspec`)
  - Permission-Microphone (from `../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/Microphone.podspec`)
  - Permission-Motion (from `../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/Motion.podspec`)
  - Permission-Notifications (from `../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/Notifications.podspec`)
  - Permission-PhotoLibrary (from `../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/PhotoLibrary.podspec`)
  - Permission-Reminders (from `../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/Reminders.podspec`)
  - Permission-Siri (from `../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/Siri.podspec`)
  - Permission-SpeechRecognition (from `../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/SpeechRecognition.podspec`)
  - Permission-StoreKit (from `../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/StoreKit.podspec`)
  - react-native-calendar-events (from `../node_modules/react-native-calendar-events`)
  - react-native-camera/FaceDetectorMLKit (from `../node_modules/react-native-camera`)
  - react-native-image-picker (from `../node_modules/react-native-image-picker`)
  - "react-native-netinfo (from `../node_modules/@react-native-community/netinfo`)"
  - react-native-onesignal (from `../node_modules/react-native-onesignal`)
  - react-native-webview (from `../node_modules/react-native-webview`)
  - React/Core (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/CxxBridge (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/DevSupport (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTActionSheet (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTAnimation (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTGeolocation (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTImage (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTLinkingIOS (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTNetwork (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTSettings (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTText (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTVibration (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTWebSocket (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - "RNCAsyncStorage (from `../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage`)"
  - RNPermissions (from `../node_modules/react-native-permissions`)
  - RNShare (from `../node_modules/react-native-share`)
  - RNSVG (from `../node_modules/react-native-svg`)
  - SwiftyJSON (= 5.0)
  - yoga (from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga`)

SPEC REPOS:
  trunk:
    - boost-for-react-native
    - Charts
    - Firebase
    - FirebaseAnalytics
    - FirebaseCore
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics
    - FirebaseInstallations
    - FirebaseInstanceID
    - FirebaseMLCommon
    - FirebaseMLVision
    - FirebaseMLVisionFaceModel
    - GoogleAPIClientForREST
    - GoogleAppMeasurement
    - GoogleDataTransport
    - GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport
    - GoogleToolboxForMac
    - GoogleUtilities
    - GTMSessionFetcher
    - nanopb
    - OneSignal
    - PromisesObjC
    - Protobuf
    - SwiftyJSON

EXTERNAL SOURCES:
  BVLinearGradient:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient"
  DoubleConversion:
    :podspec: "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec"
  Folly:
    :podspec: "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec"
  glog:
    :podspec: "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec"
  Permission-Calendars:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/Calendars.podspec"
  Permission-Camera:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/Camera.podspec"
  Permission-Contacts:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/Contacts.podspec"
  Permission-FaceID:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/FaceID.podspec"
  Permission-LocationAlways:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/LocationAlways.podspec"
  Permission-LocationWhenInUse:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/LocationWhenInUse.podspec"
  Permission-MediaLibrary:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/MediaLibrary.podspec"
  Permission-Microphone:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/Microphone.podspec"
  Permission-Motion:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/Motion.podspec"
  Permission-Notifications:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/Notifications.podspec"
  Permission-PhotoLibrary:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/PhotoLibrary.podspec"
  Permission-Reminders:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/Reminders.podspec"
  Permission-Siri:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/Siri.podspec"
  Permission-SpeechRecognition:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/SpeechRecognition.podspec"
  Permission-StoreKit:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/StoreKit.podspec"
  React:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native"
  react-native-calendar-events:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-calendar-events"
  react-native-camera:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-camera"
  react-native-image-picker:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-image-picker"
  react-native-netinfo:
    :path: "../node_modules/@react-native-community/netinfo"
  react-native-onesignal:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-onesignal"
  react-native-webview:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-webview"
  RNCAsyncStorage:
    :path: "../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage"
  RNPermissions:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-permissions"
  RNShare:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-share"
  RNSVG:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-svg"
  yoga:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga"

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  boost-for-react-native: 39c7adb57c4e60d6c5479dd8623128eb5b3f0f2c
  BVLinearGradient: e3aad03778a456d77928f594a649e96995f1c872
  Charts: e0dd4cd8f257bccf98407b58183ddca8e8d5b578
  DoubleConversion: bb338842f62ab1d708ceb63ec3d999f0f3d98ecd
  Firebase: 919186c8e119dd9372a45fd1dd17a8a942bc1892
  FirebaseAnalytics: 5fa308e1b13f838d0f6dc74719ac2a72e8c5afc4
  FirebaseCore: 8cd4f8ea22075e0ee582849b1cf79d8816506085
  FirebaseCoreDiagnostics: 4505e4d4009b1d93f605088ee7d7764d5f0d1c84
  FirebaseInstallations: 293f567159b6d66d1c990f13bb868066096c94ec
  FirebaseInstanceID: 3b119bfe90e904851218159c9a4ecb847cc51d18
  FirebaseMLCommon: 5e1184cfdddbd097f55cad75b598881d348d900f
  FirebaseMLVision: 485358b97d3332669ecc4fed55ee360aaef2813d
  FirebaseMLVisionFaceModel: 762b3af94fb29a981d76b3ab28cd1f53708f58c5
  Folly: de497beb10f102453a1afa9edbf8cf8a251890de
  glog: aefd1eb5dda2ab95ba0938556f34b98e2da3a60d
  GoogleAPIClientForREST: 9f49df9fac7867b459187e687fed3066b2be049a
  GoogleAppMeasurement: 8cd1f289d60e629cf16ab03363b9e89c776b9651
  GoogleDataTransport: 9a8a16f79feffc7f42096743de2a7c4815e84020
  GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport: 489c1265d2c85b68187a83a911913d190012158d
  GoogleToolboxForMac: 800648f8b3127618c1b59c7f97684427630c5ea3
  GoogleUtilities: 39530bc0ad980530298e9c4af8549e991fd033b1
  GTMSessionFetcher: 6f5c8abbab8a9bce4bb3f057e317728ec6182b10
  nanopb: c43f40fadfe79e8b8db116583945847910cbabc9
  OneSignal: 7dfe466265c05f02b95a274b9c997a0619ad2117
  Permission-Calendars: dc345e3388149514603309c621151ff3cfd5816a
  Permission-Camera: afad27bf90337684d4a86f3825112d648c8c4d3b
  Permission-Contacts: edde2d433382b3118f0d4c9ebc7708d5d87c4f17
  Permission-FaceID: fbdeb41087f35887f0cade55396007fadee3a234
  Permission-LocationAlways: 155e6251b757b380f6354737cae8e8d59c472495
  Permission-LocationWhenInUse: 3624cf08c12c6019926aba3054efee7f4f8ee91e
  Permission-MediaLibrary: dd1c48888cd95961fbfebdaebf8d4127c6e92e7d
  Permission-Microphone: 0ffabc3fe1c75cfb260525ee3f529383c9f4368c
  Permission-Motion: 099bc32191080089d1cb839cbae96d621a589c8f
  Permission-Notifications: 231d0e1db2300b686548587d384ba414e6a93332
  Permission-PhotoLibrary: 4d2eff62c8f4b8a27bcf045c0e36f5047efbbf20
  Permission-Reminders: 330cfafecc259594cfd7845a035580b623f771ae
  Permission-Siri: b43f74727749ce4b6acb25fe349d9e6dc4455665
  Permission-SpeechRecognition: 069447d0304a16237a43e9221052da7581d7f48c
  Permission-StoreKit: 27c9c90c94ecdc144551623a3fc14ac7488f3000
  PromisesObjC: b48e0338dbbac2207e611750777895f7a5811b75
  Protobuf: 2793fcd0622a00b546c60e7cbbcc493e043e9bb9
  React: 36d0768f9e93be2473b37e7fa64f92c1d5341eef
  react-native-calendar-events: eaa63134881d97488feb21ea114158f712894018
  react-native-camera: b5e6e34586ca6f588b0c736dcabfe0aad5ce2f3e
  react-native-image-picker: fd93361c666f397bdf72f9c6c23f13d2685b9173
  react-native-netinfo: cd479ab1b67cdd1cb1403a99ecdb24190a6dd7ef
  react-native-onesignal: 3cd5b9b5a2d151698cab987a364f4cbd51552508
  react-native-webview: 5036ed4a973ad1deeeff118262d2df7b60b3419d
  RNCAsyncStorage: d059c3ee71738c39834a627476322a5a8cd5bf36
  RNPermissions: ad71dd4f767ec254f2cd57592fbee02afee75467
  RNShare: 48cf88cadf9ca2143cdaa557c1ec7f8808040ffc
  RNSVG: 6c8e8c6f9e5a0caf910dd25aa6e4216045426e1d
  SwiftyJSON: 36413e04c44ee145039d332b4f4e2d3e8d6c4db7
  yoga: 684513b14b03201579ba3cee20218c9d1298b0cc

PODFILE CHECKSUM: 1f788ef2ef6ab1372be4b8f0741617e174e0cc14

COCOAPODS: 1.9.3
```

react-native info

```
      OS: macOS 10.15.2
      CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5350U CPU @ 1.80GHz
      Memory: 720.86 MB / 8.00 GB
      Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 12.18.2 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.22.4 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.14.6 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 13.5, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.4, watchOS 6.2
      Android SDK:
        API Levels: 28, 30
        Build Tools: 28.0.3, 30.0.0
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 4.0 AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223
      Xcode: 11.5/11E608c - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.6.0-alpha.8af6728 => 16.6.0-alpha.8af6728
      react-native: 0.59 => 0.59.10
    npmGlobalPackages:
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Open up the file `YourAppName.xcworkspace` and the clean the build with `cmd+K`

if it could not solve your problem try reseting the cache [using this link](https://gist.github.com/jarretmoses/c2e4786fd342b3444f3bc6beff32098d)

if again you are facing problem , [check this stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49603408/how-can-i-clean-my-react-native-project-to-back-it-up)

i hope it works

Comment: happy to hear you solved it.you can also accept as answer